# mysql syntax error in creating function

Tags: mysql

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS bramkiStracone;

CREATE FUNCTION bramkiStracone(idDruzyny INT)
RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE bramek INT;
DECLARE tmp1 INT;
DECLARE tmp2 INT;

SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(SUM( b.bramki ), 0) INTO tmp1
FROM LigaBramki b
INNER JOIN LigaZawodnicy z ON b.idZawodnika = z.idZawodnika
INNER JOIN LigaDruzyny d ON z.idDruzyny = d.idDruzyny
INNER JOIN LigaMecze m ON b.idMeczu = m.idMeczu
WHERE m.idDruzyny2 = idDruzyny
AND z.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND d.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND m.rozegrany = '1';

SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(SUM( b.bramki ), 0) INTO tmp2
FROM LigaBramki b
INNER JOIN LigaZawodnicy z ON b.idZawodnika = z.idZawodnika
INNER JOIN LigaDruzyny d ON z.idDruzyny = d.idDruzyny
INNER JOIN LigaMecze m ON b.idMeczu = m.idMeczu
WHERE m.idDruzyny1 = idDruzyny
AND z.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND d.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND m.rozegrany = '1';

SET bramek = tmp1 + tmp2;

RETURN bramek;
END
```

I have error near `DECLARE bramek INT;` but don't know what am i missing,
i tried to make it work by removing semi-colons but that didn't work either.

after i added delimiter i still have error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION bramkiStracone(idDruzyny INT)
RETURNS int(11)
DET' at line 1
```

Comment: The syntax is correct. Try to add DELIMITER commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

dont forget to change the default `DELIMITER` so the query won't terminate at `DECLARE bramek INT;`

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS bramkiStracone;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION bramkiStracone(idDruzyny INT)
RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE bramek INT;
DECLARE tmp1 INT;
DECLARE tmp2 INT;

SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(SUM( b.bramki ), 0) INTO tmp1
FROM LigaBramki b
INNER JOIN LigaZawodnicy z ON b.idZawodnika = z.idZawodnika
INNER JOIN LigaDruzyny d ON z.idDruzyny = d.idDruzyny
INNER JOIN LigaMecze m ON b.idMeczu = m.idMeczu
WHERE m.idDruzyny2 = idDruzyny
AND z.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND d.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND m.rozegrany = '1';

SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(SUM( b.bramki ), 0) INTO tmp2
FROM LigaBramki b
INNER JOIN LigaZawodnicy z ON b.idZawodnika = z.idZawodnika
INNER JOIN LigaDruzyny d ON z.idDruzyny = d.idDruzyny
INNER JOIN LigaMecze m ON b.idMeczu = m.idMeczu
WHERE m.idDruzyny1 = idDruzyny
AND z.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND d.idDruzyny != idDruzyny
AND m.rozegrany = '1';

SET bramek = tmp1 + tmp2;

RETURN bramek;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: now i used delimeter but still got error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION bramkiStracone(idDruzyny INT)
RETURNS int(11)
DET' at line 1

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you set the delimiter to something other than semicolon before you declare your function:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION bramkiStracone(idDruzyny INT)
RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE bramek INT;
...
END|
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your client's statement delimiter, so that it doesn't think each `;` terminates the entire `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

In the MySQL command line client, one can use the `delimiter` command:

```
delimiter ;;

CREATE FUNCTION ...  ;;

delimiter ;
```

Read the manual on [Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-defining.html).